# Determining which Active Directory user is depicted as "Guest"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How Can we check and see which individual user is attached to which "Users" OR Group in SQL Server?
I am using MS-SQL Server 2012. And I am using Active Directory to login to any application (which is in ASP .NET)

For example, In Object Explorer for any database "ABC" in SQL Server - under Security -> Users tree node - we have a user called "Guest".

Now which is the best way to determine which Active Directory user is depicted as "Guest" in SQL server?

Comment: I edited your question title as it was too vague, and there is no need for a "thank you" in your question according to the forum guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question, you could use Active Directory Administrative Center.  Not sure what permissions you would need to have (I'm a DBA so I can view all the active directory groups).  You can search for the group name and it will give you a list of all users attached to that group.

Answer (score 0):

The gust account is special. Any login that isn't a user in the database assumes the guest user. So, you won't find a specific AD account that's mapped to it; it's everyone not already a user in the database.